# How do you make an application start earlier at boot? (an atheros driver)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, boot, wifi-driver

So I have a wifi driver (the adapter is a Qualcomm Atheros qca9377 for reference) which is apparently just an executable file (QcomWlanSrvx64.exe), it doesn't show up at driverquery nor can it be seen on windows services. and the worst part is that it starts up really late after bootup (2-3 minutes after login, sometimes worse) and this can get really infuriating. I need a way for this executable to start earlier during bootup, but how am I supposed to do this? Also, if there is a simpler alternative please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That appears to be a service. Can you confirm?

Comment: The fastest way I've managed to get something to run is to create a scheduled task with the trigger "at login of any user". It's still quite slow to start after login, but not as much as 2-3 minutes.

Comment: If it is running as a service (which it should be) try updating the driver.

Comment: I rechecked, there's "AtherosSvc" which is apparently handling bluetooth, with path to executable being `C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Suite\adminservice.exe`, there's also a "WLAN AutoConfig" with `C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted -p` being its path to executable, there doesn't seem to be anything directly linked to this issue there

Comment: I figured out something, it apparently only happens when I boot up Windows after using Ubuntu. It works fine otherwise, but I need to switch between them quite a lot. Windows is still booting up via Windows Boot Manager, if I need to boot up Ubuntu I would need to press F12 to enter the boot menu than selecting GRUB there, which is listed as Ubuntu. I still don't know what really is causing this, and how I can fix it